# How to write the correct expression for regexpi? - Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

Let's say I have the following files in my_folder:

```
>> dir('my_folder')

file_001.txt file_002.txt file_003.txt file_004.txt file_005.txt file_006.txt file_007.txt file_008.txt file_009.txt file_010.txt
```

and want to create a variable in Matlab containing files 1 till 3. 
I tried the following using regular expressions:

```
>> f = dir('my_folder')
>> f1 = regexpi({f.name}, 'file_[0]?[1-3].txt', 'match')
>> f2 = [f1{:}]
```

but it didn't work...

Comment: A regex could look like this `file_00[1-3]\.txt` Don't know if thats what you mean or not.

Comment: Also, if you know the name of the files (and there are only 3) why do you need a regex?

Comment: @sln: Thanks! But isn't there a more flexible regex that chooses a file with any number of zeros followed by any number within [1-3]? For instance, if I want to select files 8 to 10 your regex won't work for the 10th file since there's only one 0.

Comment: 8-10 would be `file_0*(?:[89]|10)\.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex:

```
file_[0]?[1-3].txt
```

- `[0]?` means one or zero `0`
- `.` means any character (except newline).

So your regex will match:

```
file_01.txt, file_01atxt, file_1atxt, file_3atxt
```

but it will not match

```
file_001.txt, file_002.txt, file_003.txt
```

If you want to match file_001.txt, file_002.txt, file_003.txt then you should use the regex described by sln in the comments:

```
file_00[1-3]\.txt
```

Here the `\.` means literally a dot rather than *any character*.

If the 00 is optional (I am assuming this is why you used `?`) and you also want to match file_1.txt, file_2.txt, file_3.txt, file_01.txt, etc then the regex would be:

```
file_0*[1-3]\.txt
```

Here the `*` means zero or more characters (`0` in this case).

**Update based on comment**

If you want at least one preceding zero then you could use:

```
file_0+[1-3]\.txt
```

This would match:

```
file_01.txt, file_02.txt, file_03.txt, file_001, etc
```

`+` means one or more, whereas `?` means one or zero.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I actually wanted a regex that would select any file with either one or more zeros (I thought [0]? would do the trick) followed by any number within [1-3]. So the ideal regex would select file_01.txt, file_002.txt, file_000003.txt and so on...